# What is a modern equivalent to "fir el 201" rims

Tags: parts, wheels

What is a comparable modern-day rim to these "fir el 201" rims? I believe they came stock on a 1996 Bianchi Eros.

I need to replace the rims, and I am trying to gauge the quality that I am used to in order to set a baseline in my search.

[image: rim label]

Comment: Well, it's a 622x13.6 rim.  Count the spokes.  Doesn't appear to be a particularly "deep" rim, so any standard rim of the same size (+/- 2mm or so width) and drilling should work.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I am not so much concerned with finding something "compatible". I may replace the spokes. But I am trying to get an idea of the price range I would be looking at for rims that are comparable in terms of performance and durability.

Comment: Any bike shop should be able to help you out. It is a 700c rim with an ISO measurement of 622mm. Don't expect to reuse the spokes or nipples-they're best replaced.

Comment: @MikeEng, this isn't really the sort of place for shopping. There are going to be hundreds of viable options and while a rim might cost you $30-$100, the actual rebuild will probably cost more than the components. If you don't have experience, however, it'll be worth it having the wheel rebuilt.

Comment: @WTHarper I have built wheels, and I am considering building these myself. I don't understand your point about shopping - I thought this was a simple identification question. I am looking to determine the quality of these rims by comparison to currently available rims.

Comment: @MikeEng, what I was saying is that these are pretty generic rims and that there are very many rims that you'd do well by purchasing. Generally, StackExchange avoids questions like, "what is the best 622x13 rim" or "what is your favorite road rim". If you include more information about what sort of riding you're doing and where you're doing it, you will generally garner more response.

Comment: I think any similar (low profile box) rim from a reputable company such as Mavic or DT would be fine.  Whether you need new spokes or not depends on how much difference there is between old and new rims, and how much wear there is on the wheel.  (It's MUCH easier to swap rims if you keep the existing spokes, but very disheartening to swap rims and discover 1000 miles later that the spokes are shot.)

Comment: But note that it may be better/cheaper/simpler to just buy a whole new wheel.

Comment: The thing is excellent quality rims are not expensive. Mavic Open Pro's are < $100 US, velocity makes nice rims too for not a lot of money (both of these are going to be "better" than what you have). It is the whole wheel with the hub, spokes and labor that kicks up the cost. If you're going to replace the rim and do it yourself, you might as well get really high quality for a few extra bucks. Why merely match the original quality?

Comment: @Angelo I may indeed get a better quality rim - I just want to make sure I don't downgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [BikePedia](http://www.bikepedia.com/QUICKBIKE/BikeSpecs.aspx?Year=1996&Brand=Bianchi&Model=Eros%20%2802%29&Type=bike#.UFHGllRmTqc), these did not come stock on the Bianchi Eros in either 1996 or 1997. Since this bike came stock with Mirage level components, you're probably looking at a low - mid level quality OEM rim. Fir is/was a good brand, as is Ambrosio (which came stock on this bike). Finding a rim from [Velocity](http://www.velocityusa.com/default.asp?contentID=563) or [Alex Rims](http://www.alexrims.com/default.asp) or [Mavic](http://www.mavic.com/en/product/rims/road-triathlon/rims) just to name a few common manufacturers will provide you with a quality alternative that is affordable and readily available today.

To match the style, you are going to want to get a low profile or "box" style rim as opposed to a deep profile or "aero" rim. All of these companies and more have a style of rim like this.

You will definitely need to purchase new spokes and nipples for this, so make sure you know how to purchase the proper size.